# jquery global variables not being recognized by functions

Tags: jquery, function, global-variables

For code, please see my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6fwbS/5/

I can not get the global variables a, b, or c to change when you click on the increase button. Even though I have declared them outside any functions, the functions just don't seem to know the values of these variables. I've had a similar problem before with accessing global variables to be used in a function. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: as you can see I've even had to declare the var imgs twice. Once in each function because I could not access it as a global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how it's *supposed* to work but I'd guess you are forgetting to increment a.  Maybe you need this:

```
if (a >= imgs)
    a = 0;
else
    a++;
```

Comment: That was it... stupid me I can't believe that I missed that. Thanks man... now I have a whole new set of problems to fix. haha

Answer (score 0):

Your variables aren't changing because your code isn't changing them. a is set to 0 initially, then in document.ready it increases by 1 (a++). a never changes after that. imgs never changes after that. So b and c, because they rely on the value of a in order to change, never change. What are you trying to accomplish here? Perhaps the answer to your question is: when should a change?

EDIT: Perhaps this is what you're trying to do with the variables? http://jsfiddle.net/6fwbS/16/

Answer (score 0):

you have declared `imgs` variable inside `$("#thumb_slider").children().each(function(index, element) {` function, so your `slide_img_left()` do not have access to it, because it has been declared in a local scope of that function. try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6fwbS/14/